# How do I run my .jar file where I wrote my Beam pipeline on Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wrote a .jar file with an Apache Beam pipeline (written in Java) that I want to run Google Dataflow. I loaded it into a bucket. When I go on the Dataflow UI, there's only one option: Create Job from Template. But I can't use my .jar file there. How do I get my pipeline "into" Dataflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.16.0 \
      -DgroupId=org.example \
      -DartifactId=word-count-beam \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=org.apache.beam.examples \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After running the command, you should see a new directory called word-count-beam under your current directory. word-count-beam contains a simple pom.xml

To run the job using the DataflowRunner you would need to execute the below command

```
mvn -Pdataflow-runner compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
      -Dexec.args="--project=<PROJECT_ID> \
      --stagingLocation=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/staging/ \
      --output=gs://<STORAGE_BUCKET>/output \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

Please refer to this link on how to run Java based Cloud Dataflow - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven

Comment: Hi, that's for the word count example. How do I do this with my own java file?

Comment: change the  `-Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount` to your main class.

Comment: Thank you! Can i do the first step using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes it is a simple maven build. If this answer helped you please do accept the answer.

Comment: Why we are running mvn archetype:generate  this command?